# Manifest v3 sandboxed origin in iframe doesn't have media devices permissions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, manifest.json

our sandboxed application is wrapped by a top level html, which servers as a proxy between our app and service workers.

I need access to microphone in the application, `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: {deviceId: {exact: 'default'}} })`, but it seems like we cannot do that in a sandboxed origin? `[Violation] Permissions policy violation: microphone is not allowed in this document.`

I haven't seen any mention of the navigator.mediaDevices being blocked in a sandboxed origin. But if that's the case, is my only workaround to handle audio in the wrapper?

Here's what I've been trying to do

Top level wrapper:

```
let iframe = document.createElement('iframe'),
    appUrl = chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html');

iframe.setAttribute('src', appUrl);
iframe.setAttribute('allow', 'microphone ' + appUrl);
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Permissions in manifest.json:

```
"permissions": [
    "notifications",
    "storage",
    "notifications",
    "scripting",
    "contentSettings"
],
```

Comment: here you go [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#document_source_security)

Comment: I thought this only applied to a sandboxed iframe, as in an iframe with sandbox attribute? Also another weird thing to me is that the `window.isSecureContext` flag is set to true.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I thought you said "sandboxed origin" 4 times, I did not realise that you were not talking about the iframe at all - I obviously have no clue what a "sandboxed origin" is

Comment: I see, [this is what I meant](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/manifest/sandbox).
Unfortunately doesn't seem like getting audio in such context is possible. [link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/iframe-embed-object.html#attr-iframe-sandbox)